# Free Wordpress account REST API authentication in python

Tags: python, wordpress, python-requests

I'm currently trying to make a post on a blog that I created using a free account on wordpress.com. I don't have complete knowledge in this field yet so I'm trying to see if this is possible since what I'm building is just a small project. If not, I would have to learn to host a WordPress website on GitHub pages. Here's my code so far:

```py
import requests
import base64

username = # my username
password = # my password

credentials = username + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()) 
header = {'Authorization':'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

# api_url = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/{my website\'s url}/posts/new'
api_url = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/{my website\'s url}/posts/new'

data = {
    'title' : 'Example wordpress post',
    'status': 'publish',
    'slug' : 'example-post',
    'author': 1,
    'content': 'This is the content of the post'
}

# headers = {
#     'Authorization' : f'Basic {base64_string}'
# }

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {username}:{password}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.post(api_url,headers=header, json=data)

print(response)
```

I tried two ways to generate the headers and I'm also trying to use my account username and password if that even works. It's currently returning a <Response [403]>

Comment: I don't think you can use basic auth to access that API.